# Using CUDA with an intel gpu

Tags: python, cuda, nvidia, intel

I'm trying to use an AI software called `DreamCraft3D` https://mrtornado24.github.io/DreamCraft3D/. I want to use it in order to create an application software on my own. However, I am quite new to coding and really want to use this. However, its installation requires NVIDIA to use CUDA, and I have an Intel mac. I still want to mess around with this software and see what its capable of. Can someone walk me through using this?

I have created a project file and set up pip, and tried to skip over CUDA by using docker, however the software didn't work out well and was a pain too use. Again, if any of you have the time to help me out with trying to figure this out thx a lot.

Comment: Buy a new computer with a good Nvidia GPU. This is the best solution. That code only works on Nvidia GPU. Even if you've refactored it for an Intel CPU(because you have an Intel Mac), you will wait days to generate something due to the high computing cost.